# Retaining CMSampleBufferRef from camera feed

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I'm writing AR app that uses camera feed to take pictures positioned on certain places in the world. Now I came upon problem that I'm not sure what to do about.

I'm using CVOpenGLESTextureCacheRef to create textures from CMSampleBufferRef. The camera feed is being shown and it works perfectly. The problem occurs when I capture 12 photos and create textures from them. The way it works is that once I detect match with the target I create a texture like this:

```
CVImageBufferRef pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBufferCopy);

size_t frameWidth = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer);
size_t frameHeight = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer);
CVOpenGLESTextureRef texture = NULL;
CVReturn err = CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                            cache,
                                                            pixelBuffer,
                                                            NULL,
                                                            GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                                                            GL_RGBA,
                                                            (GLsizei)frameWidth,
                                                            (GLsizei)frameHeight,
                                                            GL_BGRA,
                                                            GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                                                            0,
                                                            &texture);


if (!texture || err) {
    NSLog(@"CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage failed (error: %d)", err);
    return;
}

CVOpenGLESTextureCacheFlush(cache, 0);
```

The texture is then mapped to photo location in the world and is being rendered. I am not releasing texture here because I need it in the future. The texture used as the camera feed is obviously being released.

The issue appears when 12th photo is taken. The `captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:` callback is not being called anymore. I understand it happens because the pool is full, like pointed out in documentation:

> If your application is causing samples to be dropped by retaining the provided CMSampleBufferRef objects for too long, but it needs access to the sample data for a long period of time, consider copying the data into a new buffer and then releasing the sample buffer (if it was previously retained) so that the memory it references can be reused.

However I am not sure what to do. I tried using `CMSampleBufferCreateCopy` to create a copy of the buffer but it did not work because like documentation says, it creates a shallow copy.

How do I handle this in a most efficient way?

Comment: Added answer how to take sampleBuffer ownership here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36893192/440168